# Location manager getLastKnownLocation() caches last fix?

Tags: android

I'm registering for location updates:

```
public void onResume() {
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);
    for (String it : providers) {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(it, 0, 0, myListener);
    }
}
```

Now will any new location fixes received be cached in the providers? In other words, if the gps listener got a new fix 1 second ago, calling the following:

```
Location loc = lm.getProvider("gps").getLastKnownLocation("gps");
```

should give me back that latest location, right? Just wondering if there's any policy for a provider where it might not return back its latest fix (ie. it receives a fix, but the internal implementation doesn't cache it as the last known location for some reason, or there's some timeout before it gets served up as the last-known),

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check source of [LocationManagerService.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java) you can see the last known location for provider is updated if the location provider is enabled, so the answer is Yes.

Comment: PS: You can use loc.getTime() to get the UTC time of this fix.